# How to find the normal form of the given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title suggests, I am having difficulty in finding the normal form of the equation
$$y''-2\tan(\tan x)+xy=0$$ given  $$y=u\sec(\sec x)$$ Direct substitution isn't working out as it is pretty complex. I tried using the formula that for any general DE of the form $$ y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0,$$ the normal form is given by $$u''+h(x)u=0,\qquad h(x)=q(x)-\frac{p^2}{4}-\frac{p'}{2},$$
but this is also pretty complex and isn't helping me, or atleast I am unable to see how to proceed majorly due to tan(tanx) term. Also, am not sure if the formula is applicable as I am not sure if $e^{\int \tan(\tan x)}=\sec(\sec x)$ or not. Kindly help! Thank you!

Comment: What about $y''+py'+qy=r$? The normal forms you try are all homogeneous, but there is no reason to be restricted to them.

Comment: But like how am I supposed to add r(x), also as far as i remember, the solution had r(x) as zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have typo in the ode. You are missing $y'$. Second the exponential with hard integral drops out.

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}-2\tan(\tan(x))y^{\prime}+xy  & =0\\
y^{\prime\prime}+py^{\prime}+qy  & =0
\end{align*}

Let the substituion be
\begin{align*}
u  & =ye^{\int pdx}\\
& =ye^{\int-2\tan(\tan(x))dx}%
\end{align*}
Applying this change of variable to the ode gives (after simplification) (note, keep the integral unevaluated)

$$
e^{\int\tan(\tan(x))dx}\left(  u\left(  \sec\left(  \tan x\right)  )^{2}
\sec^{2}x-\tan\left(  \tan x\right)  ^{2}+x\right)  +u^{\prime\prime}\right)
=0
$$

Since $e^{\int\tan(\tan(x))dx}\neq0$ the above simplifies to

$$
u^{\prime\prime}=\left(  -\sec\left(  \tan x\right)  )^{2}\sec^{2}
x+\tan\left(  \tan x\right)  ^{2}-x\right)  u
$$

Which is the normal form $u''=r u$ of the original ode.

Comment: Ok I was getting a similar answer but the point is that it somehow further simplified to contain only x as coeff of u, is this possible?

Comment: @SanyamJain I do not understand what you mean. Do you mean $r$ simplifies to only $x$? I do not see how this is possible. the normal form is $u''=r u$ as shown, where $r$ that that term inside `( .... )`

Comment: Yes, that is what was confusing me essentially. I am also not sure how that is possible. But again, it was an online doc and typos are possible. But if there is a way, I will wait for someone to find it.Otherwise this was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @SanyamJain I used Maple to do the change of variables as I did not feel like doing the tedious calculus now. So I doubt there is an error in its result. Here is the code, you can try it yourself if you have Maple `ode:=diff(y(x),x$2)-2*tan(tan(x))*diff(y(x),x)+x*y(x)=0;
p:=-2*tan(tan(x));
PDEtools:-dchange({y(x)=u(x)/exp(1/2*Int(p,x))},ode,{u});
`

Comment: So essentially what you have given is fine, right? Sorry I don't have Maple

Comment: @SanyamJain Here is a screen shot, so you can see for yourself. I just dropped the exp() term and simplified the expression.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cvz1.png)  You can try Wolfram alpha, it is free site if you do not have Maple.